# Php Mysql Search Between Two Dates

Tags: php, mysql

I've mysql table like this:

```
id      start_date         username
1       2013-04-04         18
2       2013-03-31         19
3       2013-04-04         19
4       2013-04-02         19 
5       2013-04-03         18
```

I'm trying to get **username** where start_date is between 2013-03-31 to 2013-05-01 with following query:

```
// $from = 2013-03-31 and $to = 2013-03-01 (example)

$search = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM oc_calendar WHERE start_date >'$from' AND 
start_date < '$to'"); 
$re_search = mysql_fetch_array($search);
echo $search_p_id = $re_search['username'];
```

But It's just print username = 18, It's should be print 18 and 19 number username. why it's doesn't show? Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Query:**

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM oc_calendar WHERE 
start_date between '$from' AND '$to'");
```

And you need a while-loop to display more that one username and a correct SQL-query (see above):

```
while($re_search = mysql_fetch_array($search)) {
  $re_search['username'] . '<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT username FROM oc_calendar WHERE start_date between '$from' AND '$to'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query :

```
$search = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM oc_calendar WHERE start_date between '$from' AND '$to'");
```

Regarding the condition that you are using :

```
where start_date >'$from'
```

your fromdate = 2013-03-31 so the above mentioned condition is not true for username = 19. Instead you should use

```
where start_date >= '$from' and startdate <='$to'
```

Comment: Well, your update query is not show the 18 and 19 number username.