# How to replace the multiple %s inside sprintf in a date_format?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to replace all the `%s` in the query with the given days. But it throws me and error at the `Date_format.` The `%s` in the `fcst_date` is getting replaced correctly. Please help

```
    $day1 = date('Y-m-d');
    $day2 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 days"));
    $day3 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+2 days"));
    $day4 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+3 days"));
    $day5 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+4 days"));
    $day6 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+5 days"));
    $day7 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+6 days"));
    $day8 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 days"));
    $day9 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+8 days"));
    $day10 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+9 days"));
    $query = sprintf('SELECT blk_id,blk_name,fcst_date,temp_max,max_temp,date,temp_stn_block.stn_id FROM temp_stn_block RIGHT JOIN temp_stn_normals ON temp_stn_block.stn_id=temp_stn_normals.stn_id INNER JOIN block_imd_gfs_forecast ON blk_id=block_id JOIN block_s ON block_s.id=blk_id WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date, "%%m-%%d") IN DATE_FORMAT("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s", "%%m-%%d") AND fcst_date IN (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", $day1, $day2, $day3, $day4,$day5, $day6, $day7,$day8,$day9,$day10, $day1, $day2, $day3, $day4,$day5, $day6, $day7,$day8,$day9,$day10);
    $res = $this->db->query($query);
    return $res->result();
```

Comment: A few things - there is a missing `'` at the end of the string part in sprintf.  You may be better off using SQL BETWEEN rather than the way your doing it and Please use prepared statements.

Comment: Use a prepared statement, not `sprintf`.

Comment: @NigelRen could u give me an example??

Comment: Not sure which part you mean but - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438230/php-mysql-search-between-two-dates and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1290975/how-to-create-a-secure-mysql-prepared-statement-in-php

Comment: I mean how to change my query to the one that u r telling me to use. i need to show the data of the the 10 dates. can u edit my query??

Answer (score 0):

I would rather used prepared statements with named param for this just for a more readable code. But then you would have to update your codeigniter db config to use PDO driver.

For `sprintf`, just used numbered placeholders:

```php
$qry_str = 'SELECT 
 blk_id,blk_name,fcst_date,temp_max,max_temp,date,temp_stn_block.stn_id 
 FROM temp_stn_block 
 RIGHT JOIN temp_stn_normals 
   ON temp_stn_block.stn_id=temp_stn_normals.stn_id 
 INNER JOIN block_imd_gfs_forecast 
   ON blk_id=block_id JOIN block_s ON block_s.id=blk_id 
 WHERE 
   DATE_FORMAT(date, "%%m-%%d") BETWEEN *day1* AND *day10*
 AND 
   fcst_date IN (%1$s, %2$s, %3$s, %4$s, %5$s, %6$s, %7$s, %8$s, %9$s, %10$s)"
';

$query = sprintf($qry_str, $day1, $day2, $day3, $day4, $day5, $day6, $day7, $day8, $day9, $day10);

$res = $this->db->query($query);
```

I think the issue with your query is the usage of `%s` which is a specifier for 'seconds' in `DATE_FORMAT`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DATE_FORMAT("2019-02-05, 2019-02-06, 2019-02-07, 2019-02-08, 2019-02-09, 2019-02' i got ths error after using ur query xDiff

Comment: Oops, my bad, I overlooked in that `DATE_FORMAT` only accepts two parameters. You should use BETWEEN *day1* AND *day10* instead, updated the query

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near * day1 * AND * day10 * now this is the error i m getting. what is the meaning of * character ? xDiff

Comment: I have used WHERE 
               DATE_FORMAT(date, "%%m-%%d") BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT("%1$s", "%%m-%%d") AND DATE_FORMAT("%10$s", "%%m-%%d") but it is returning me just the last date not the range of dates