# How to implement between search filter in php?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am implementing search filter with `date_of_birth` and other `4` column. search filter is working right with other `4` column.

But now I need to filter with `date_of_birth` like I need all data between two dates.

Currently my `vaivahik_list.php` look like this

```
<?php
include "../connection.php";
extract($_REQUEST);
$perPage = 50; // total records per page
// page
$conditionArr = array(); // array for condition
$condition = ""; // conditions
$pages = ""; // how many pages created
$type = "";
$company = "";
$message = "";
$rersArr = array();
$data = array();
$templeArr = array();

$sdate = substr($byear,0,4);
$edate = substr($byear1,0,4);

if ($sabhasadnumber != "") {
    array_push($conditionArr, "sabhasad_number LIKE '%" . $sabhasadnumber . "%'");
}
if ($Sakhe != "") {
    array_push($conditionArr, "sakhe_id LIKE '%" . $Sakhe . "%'");
}
if ($gen != "") {
    array_push($conditionArr, "gender LIKE '%" . $gen . "%'");
}

if($village_id != ""){
    array_push($conditionArr,"village_id = '".$village_id."'");
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE is_active = 1 and status = 1 AND metrimonial  = 1 ";
if (sizeOf($conditionArr) > 0) {
    $condition = implode(" AND ", $conditionArr);
//    echo $condition;
    $sql .= " AND $condition";

}
$start = ($page - 1) * $perPage;
$sql1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($sql1);
$pages = ceil($count / $perPage);
$sql .= " ORDER BY members_id ASC";
$sql .= " limit $start,$perPage ";
?>
<input type="hidden" name="total_page" id="total_page" value="<?php echo $pages; ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="current_page" class="current_page" id="current_page"
                   value="<?php echo $page; ?>">
    <div class="member--items">
                                <div class="row gutter--15 AdjustRow">

                                    <div class="row">
<?php
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>


   <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 col-xxs-12" style="height:300px">

                                                <div class="member--item ">

                                                    <?php
                                                    $imgurl = "";
                                                    if ($row["image"] != "") {
                                                        $imgurl = "../admin/uploads/" . $row["image"];
                                                    } else {
                                                        $imgurl = "../admin/uploads/default_profile.jpg";
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                    <div class="img img-circle">
                                                        <a href="sabhasad_family.php?id=<?php echo $row['sabhasad_number']; ?>" class="btn-link">
                                                            <img src="<?php echo $imgurl; ?>" alt=""
                                                                 style="height: 150px; width: 150px;">
                                                        </a>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="name">
                                                        <h3 class="h fs--12">
                                                            <p>
                                                                <a href="sabhasad_family.php?id=<?php echo $row['sabhasad_number']; ?>"> <?php echo $row['surname'] ." " ;

                                                                    echo $row['name'] ." ";

                                                                    echo $row['middle_name'] ." "; ?></a></p>

                                                        </h3>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="activity">
                                                        <p>સભાસદ નંબર : <?php echo $row['sabhasad_number']; ?> </p>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>





    <?php
}
}
else { ?>

    <?php
}
?>
```

`vaivahik.js`

```
    $.ajax({
        url: "process/vaivahik_list.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {
            sabhasadnumber: $("#sabhasadnumber").val(),
            village_id: $("#Village").val(),
            Sakhe: $("#Sakhe").val(),
            gen: $("#gender").val(),
            byear:$("#byear").val(),
            byear1:$("#byear1").val(),
            page: page
        },
        success: function (data) {
            if (searches === true) {
                $("#mlist").html(data);
            } else {
                $("#mlist").append(data);
            }
        }
    });
```

`vaivahik.php`

```
     <form action="#">
            <div class="row">


                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            <span class="text-darker ff--primary fw--500">શોધી રહ્યો છુ</span>

                            <select name="gender" id="gender" class="form-control form-sm"
                                    data-trigger="selectmenu">
                                <option value=" ">પસંદ કરો</option>
                                <option value="F">સ્ત્રી
                                </option>
                                <option value="M">પુરુષ</option>

                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            <span class="text-darker ff--primary fw--500">સભાસદ નંબર</span>

                            <input type="text" name="sabhasadnumber" id="sabhasadnumber"
                                   class="form-control form-sm"
                                   placeholder="સભાસદ નંબર">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            <span class="text-darker ff--primary fw--500">Starting Year</span>

                            <input type="date" name="byear" id="byear"
                                   class="form-control form-sm"
                                   placeholder="જન્મ વર્ષ">
                      vaiva  </label>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>
                            <span class="text-darker ff--primary fw--500">End Year</span>

                            <input type="date" name="byear1" id="byear1"
                                   class="form-control form-sm"
                                   placeholder="જન્મ વર્ષ">
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>

                            <span class="text-darker ff--primary fw--500">સાખે</span>

                            <select class="form-control form-sm" name="Sakhe" id="Sakhe">
                                <option value=""> સાખે પસંદ કરો
                                </option>
                                <?php
                                $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from sakhe where status = 1 order by sakhe_id asc");
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                                    echo "<option value = " . $row['sakhe_id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-6 col-xxs-12">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>

                            <span class="text-darker ff--primary fw--500">ગામ પસંદ કરો</span>

                            <select class="form-control"
                                    name="Village"
                                    id="Village">
                                <option value="">ગામ પસંદ કરો
                                </option>
                                <?php
                                $query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from village where status = 1 AND is_active = 1 order by village_id asc");
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                                    echo "<option value = " . $row['village_id'] . ">" . $row['name'] . "</option>";
                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <button type="button" onclick="getresult()" class="btn btn-primary"
                            id="shopsubmit" name="shopsubmit">
                        સબમિટ કરો
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
                            id="reset" name="reset">
                        ફરીથી સેટ કરો
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

I am getting Starting Date in `$sdate` and Ending date in `$edate`.

and I have stored `Date_of_birth` in `1/Jun/1958` format in tables.

Now I need to implement search all data between two dates.

I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Please be more specific about your question.. and from where $byear is coming?

Comment: do you want something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15438230/php-mysql-search-between-two-dates

Comment: I have edited two files @AmanjotKaur

Comment: can you give me an example what you want?

Comment: let's say I have `01-JAN-1997` `01-JAN-1998` `01-JAN-1999` as  `date_of_birth`  in tables. now I need all records between `1997` and `1998`.  So it returns alll records between `01-JAN-1997` AND  `01-JAN-1998`  . @AmanjotKaur

Comment: the main problem is the date format in the database. you must use the proper format, `date`.

Comment: As for the task in general, here you go - [how to create a search filter with mysqli](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli_examples/search_filter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$from= date("Y",strtotime($start_year));
$to= date("Y",strtotime($end_year));
$search = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE start_date between '$from' AND '$to'");
```

And make sure in DB the data is stored in YYYY-MM-DD Format.. using the datatype date.

> MySQL uses YYYY-MM-DD format for storing a date value

Comment: mysql_query doesn't exist. Use DateTime class instead of strtotime